# Separating and recovering elements from TransformGroup in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, custom-controls

On my MainPage.xaml I have some custom UserControls which I want to be able to move all over the Grid surface. That is the reason why I am adding them all to TransformGroup:

```
            this.transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
            this.translation = new TranslateTransform();
            this.scale = new ScaleTransform();

            this.transformGroup.Children.Add(this.scale);
            this.transformGroup.Children.Add(this.translation);

            myCustomControl1.RenderTransform = this.transformGroup;
            myCustomControl2.RenderTransform = this.transformGroup;
```

Now I can move all my custom controls what gives me "scrolling effect" on the Grid (something like scrolling the Bing Maps effect).

My problem is:
I want to be able to seperate my Custom control from the TransformGroup and move it independent from the rest. In myCustomControl.xaml.cs I have:

```
private void separateControlFromTransformGroup()
    {
        Grid parentGrid = (Grid)Parent;
        this.transformGroup = (TransformGroup)this.RenderTransform;//backup copy of old transform group
        newTransformGroup1 = new TransformGroup(); //new temporary transform group
        TranslateTransform translation1 = new TranslateTransform();
        CopyTranslateTransform((TranslateTransform)transformGroup.Children[1], translation1);//copy the values of transformGroup from the MainPage.xaml to temporary one (not reference)
        ScaleTransform scale1 = new ScaleTransform();
        CopyScale((ScaleTransform)transformGroup.Children[0], scale1);

        newTransformGroup1.Children.Add(scale1);
        newTransformGroup1.Children.Add(translation1);
        foreach (myCustomControl brother in parentGrid.Children)
        {
            if (brother == this)
            {
                continue; (separate this control from the TransformGroup)
            }
            else
            {
                 brother.RenderTransform = newTransformGroup1; //the rest of myCustromControls on the Grid in MainPage.xaml now have diffrent transform group. Now I can move selected control independent from the rest

            }
        }
    }
```

After moving the separate myCustomControl (with new values) I can't connect it with the rest in a transformGroup and be able to move the all together againg. What should I Do? Is there any other way to make controls 'moveAble' on the Grid if none selected, or select just one if any selected?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be creating a separate TransformGroupd for each user control. You might consider having a container control that you add all the user controls with it's own TransformGroup, this transform group will affect all the controls while the individual per control transform group is used to affect the individual controls.

You might also consider wiring this all together directly in XAML.

So the MainPage might have the layout Grid with a child Grid which acts as the container for all the Controls, this is what will be translated and scaled to affect all the child controls.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">  
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid x:Name="Container">
      <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
          <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContainerTranslation" />
          <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContainerScale" />
        </TransformGroup>
      </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then the child controls can be added to the `Constainer`, each with their own Translation and Scale transform. The child control might be something like this.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.EntityControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="50"
    Width="50" Height="50">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
      <TransformGroup>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="Translation" />
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="Scale" />
      </TransformGroup>      
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code behind can expose some properties that you can access to affect the Translation and Scaling of the Entity controls.

Comment: That works well, but when I am moving one Independent control the Translation from ContainerGrid (in MainPage.xaml) affects it anyway. The control, that is being dragged moving faster on the surface (but the rest of the controls are moving as well)

Comment: @xawer, you will need to share some code to show how you are affecting the transforms so that we can better understand what you mean. If you adjust only the transform of one of the entity instances then only that entity should be affected, if you adjust the transform of the container then all controls are affected along with the container. So I am not sure what you mean with your scenario.